# When select one option from "multiple select", remove it from other selects (and reverse)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have 3 multiple selects like:

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>

<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>

<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>
```

and I am looking for best solution. Wanted behaviour is when you select one item in one multi select, then remove it from the others (and conversely).

I using jquery Chosen plugin.
Situation: you have 3 roles, but user can be just in one role.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NFLk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you want to remove the option via JS/jQuery and the update the plugin.

Here is some code

```
  $(".chzn-select").change(function(){   
    $(".chzn-select")   
    .not($(this))  
    .find("option[value="+$(this).val()+"]")   
    .remove();   
    $(".chzn-select").trigger("liszt:updated");   
   });
```

and a fiddle link [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UYa9k/)

EDIT:
try this new fiddle it handles multiple select

```
$(".chzn-select").css('width', '300px').chosen({
        display_selected_options: false,
        no_results_text: 'not found',
    }).change(function(){
        var me = $(this);
        $(".chzn-container .search-choice").each(function(){
            var text = $('span',this).text();
            $(".chzn-select")
            .not(me)
            .find("option").each(function(){
               if ($(this).text() == text) $(this).prop('disabled',true);
            });
        });
        $(".chzn-select").trigger("liszt:updated");
});
```

**EDITED:**
try this:
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/URBNq/1/)
see if it pleases you... :)

Comment: hm... still you can select one item in more than one (multi) select http://d.pr/i/lSUl

Comment: Are you sure?  Did you use the latest link?

Comment: You were right, For some reason the latest version wasn't saved. Try it now. It disables the option everywhere after it has been selected no matter where it is selected.

Comment: Hi, there is one more bug. When you add some option to the select box, you can't remove it later. The [X] button is missing. I think that the problem is that the .search-choice is without <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="4"></a>(http://d.pr/i/kHMv) how to fix this?

Comment: It depends on text because the element that verifies if it already exists on has information on the text and not the value (it's a `<span>` element). I still don't know why the "x" was removed.